# SQL case statement in a View logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2014

```
CREATE VIEW [Myview] AS
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN 
    DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0))='Sunday'
    THEN
        SELECT 
            cast(DATEPART(yyyy, getdate()-7) as varchar(4)) as YEAR,
            RIGHT('00'+cast(DATEPART(ww, getdate()-7) as varchar(2)),2) as WEEK;    
    ELSE
        SELECT 
            cast(DATEPART(yyyy, getdate()-14) as varchar(4)) as YEAR,
            RIGHT('00'+cast(DATEPART(ww, getdate()-14) as varchar(2)),2) as WEEK;
GO
```

> Error while creating: Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Parse
> error at line: 8, column: 3: Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'.

Help me out to fix this error.
I want to check if the 1st day of the year is Sunday then I would follow the then statement. Then statement suggest to get week id and year.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQKH0.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  Your code doesn't help me at least understand what you want to do.

Comment: You have 2 `SELECT` in your `VIEW`'s definition, but the latter is *inside* the `CASE` **expression**. You also have 2 statements (there's statement terminator (`;`) in the middle of your `CASE`) but a `VIEW` is a pseudo table who's definition is defined by *single* statement. Also, as a emphasised, `CASE` is an *expression*, not a statement; it returns a scalar valid and you are trying to define 2 column inside it. A quick read of the `CASE` **expressions** [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) will show you how wrong your syntax is.

Comment: In truth, the above doesn't even feel like it should be a `VIEW`. It's not returning data from any tables. I, suspect, it would be better written as an **inline** table value function.

Comment: No FROM clauses?!?

Comment: So when i use the below quey:
cast(DATEPART(yyyy, getdate()-7) as varchar(4)) as YEAR,
            RIGHT('00'+cast(DATEPART(ww, getdate()-7) as varchar(2)),2) as WEEK

It gives me output as a table of the current year and current week.
But there is this condition which I want to implement:
DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0))='Sunday'

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your SQL. Firstly you have 3 `SELECT` statements in your query; 2 of which are inside your `CASE` **Expression**. A `VIEW` is a pseudo table who's definition is defined by a *single* statement ending in a `SELECT`. You have 2/3 statements here so it's not a valid definition for a `VIEW`.

Next, as I emphasised, `CASE` is an **expression** in T-SQL, *not* a Statement. T-SQL does *not* support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, only `CASE` expressions. `CASE` expressions return a scalar value; not statements, not boolean results. This means that you can only return **one** atomic value from the expression, and therefore each expression `WHEN` and the `ELSE` must result in a scalar value too.

Looking at what you've attempted here, however, I'm not even sure it belongs as a `VIEW`. It doesn't reference any tables, which normally a `VIEW` would. I would, personally, suggest this is better off as a inline table value function, which (if I understand what you are attempting correctly) would look like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.YourFunction()
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT CASE V.DayName WHEN 'Sunday' THEN DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, -7,GETDATE())) --I suggest leaving this as a strongly typed int
                          ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, -7,GETDATE())) --I suggest leaving this as a strongly typed int
           END AS [Year],
           CASE V.DayName WHEN 'Sunday' THEN DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, -7,GETDATE())) --I suggest leaving this as a strongly typed int
                          ELSE DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, -7,GETDATE()))
           END AS [Week]
    FROM (VALUES(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0))))V(DayName);
GO
```

I also tidy up some of your SQL> For example I use the same keywords consistently for the date parts like `YEAR`and `WEEK` (you used both `yy` and `yyyy` for year), and replace the logic that treats dates like an `int` with explicit `DATEADD` logic, as that works with *any* date and time data type (not just the old `(small)datetime` data types).

You would then call the function like so:

```sql
--On it's own
SELECT [Year], [Week]
FROM dbo.YourFunction();

--When using other tables
SELECT {Some Columns}
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.YourFunction() YF;
```